# Efficiently generate a sawtooth with rounded peaks.

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

I'd like to have an efficient function that would generate a wave that is close to a sawtooth but has slightly rounded peaks. The wave needs to be continuous at all points.  I will be doing this in directx and opengl shaders so I have access to vector units and matrix multiplies.

EDIT: I can efficiently generate a sawtooth with the following line of code: (assuming t [0,1])

```
saturate(t*10.0) - t;
```

The problem with this is that the line isn't continuous.  I'm considering sampling 4 points on the line (2 before t and 2 after) and then doing a Catmul Rom spline, but I'd be interested in any suggestions for a better way to do the smoothing.

Comment: Why don't you generate a function for a sawtooth on a closed interval, then Fourier transform it?

Comment: If it's a periodic function, definitely consider the Fourier series

Comment: I wouldn't think that fast Fourier transforming it would be very fast. (I could be wrong, I'm not very knowledgeable about how to implement a fft)

Comment: If the function is periodic and fixed you could define one period of the function and save in memory.

Comment: What about this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430564/equation-of-a-tilted-sine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following polynomial gives a single 'tooth' on domain $[-1, 1]$. The higher $n$, the sharper the peak.

$$
p\left(x\right)=x\left(1-x^{2n}\right)
$$

Repeat the function to extend the domain to $\mathbb{R}$:

$$
f\left(x\right)=p\left(\left(x\bmod 2\right)-1\right)
$$

A screenshot from [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator):

[image: Graph of function f]

Note: $f$ and $f'$ are continuous, but the second derivative is not continuous.

As for efficiency: $n$ is integer, so $x^{2n}$ can be calculated with a sequence of $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ multiplications.

Comment: Four year old question gets a good answer. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs a smooth sawtooth function that is *infinitely differentiable* ($C^{\infty}$):
there are various ways to construct such a function, typically by combining trigonometric functions.

One way is to start with a smooth square wave like:

$$
s\left(x\right)=\tanh\left(n\cos x\right)
$$

or:

$$
s\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(n\cos x\right)
$$

(the higher $n$, the sharper the edges)

Let the square wave flip a triangle wave to produce a sawtooth:

$$
f\left(x\right)=\arcsin\left(s\left(x\right)\sin x\right)
$$

Screenshot from [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator):

[image: Graph of function f]

Obviously, this is likely to be more computationally expensive than the polynomial in my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4509147/204671).
But that one, being a piecewise function, offers only $C^{1}$ continuity.

Other suggestions can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38293